# How to work with PXImageUploader in Acumatica

Tags: erp, acumatica

I want to add image uploader to my web form in Acumatica. But I hardly imagine what fields should be presented in DAC and in DB. Another question which I have is how to manage storage for images.

Is it possible to store them in db, cloud, file system?

Answer (score 1):

ImageUploader uses the files attached to an entity plus (optionally) a string field that can store the selected file name (screen title + (entity key values) + \ file name, to be precise). Since these are just regular attached files the usual storage options apply (i.e. DB or whatever storage provider you use). The files that are displayed have extensions marked as "Image" in file upload preferences.

There's nothing special about the filename field really. You need add a string to your DAC:

```
public partial class YourEntity : PX.Data.IBqlTable {
...
    public abstract class filename : PX.Data.IBqlField{}

    [PXDBString(255, IsUnicode = true)]
    public virtual string Filename { get; set; }
...
}
```

add a corresponding field to your database:

```
create table "YourEntity" ( 
...
"Filename" nvarchar(255) null,
...
)
```

and specify that field name in aspx page when adding a control:

```
<px:PXImageUploader ID="controlField" runat="server" DataField="Filename" ...
```

The user will be able to pick the selected image by on-screen arrows (or Ctrl - arrow keyboard combo) from all the attached images.

It's possible not to use the filename field at all. In that case the control will show the first attached image, and the user will be able to scroll through all the attached images.

Comment: Can you please extend you answer with some advises of how to apply this to DAC, aspx, configuration?